# Android Lollipop: What's the correct way to install apps as a system app?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I recently rooted my phone and tried to fresh install an .apk (Xperia Keyboard) right to `system/app`, and also tried to move a user app to system app (Google photos) using ES File Explorer. I moved the .apks set the correct permissions on the file and the folder, then remounted `/system` to readonly.

Sadly the result was the same with both apps and after several retries: after reboot, Everything I moved to the `system/app` folder was completely missing.

Did I miss something, or did something change in system app install after lollipop update?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Samething here. Did you find some answer?

Comment: Sadly not, stuck with user apps for now.